# Genus of a curve: topology vs algebraic geometry

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

In topology one defines the genus  $g$ of a connected  orientable topological manifold $X$ as:

> The maximum number $g$ of cuttings along non-intersecting closed simple curves without rendering the resultant manifold disconnected. It is equal to the number of handles on it.

Now, if $X$ is an irreducible curve, Fulton defines the genus of $X$ via the Riemann's theorem:

[image]
Here $l(D)$ is the dimension of the vector space $$\mathcal O_X(D)(X)=L(D)=\{f\in K^\ast(=k(X)^\ast)\,:\, div(f)+D\ge 0\}\cup \{0\}$$ over $k$.

How can I prove that both the definitions of the genus $g$ represent the same thing? In wich way the Fulton's genus represent the "number of holes" of $X$?

Answer (score 14):

One way to explain the connection is via the *Hodge decomposition* of the (singular) cohomology groups of an algebraic variety.

1. On one hand, viewing $X$ as a two-dimensional real manifold, and using say Mayer--Vietoris, one proves that $H_1(X,\mathbf{Z}) \cong \mathbf{Z}^{2g}$, and hence by duality, $H^1(X,\mathbf{C}) \cong \mathbf{C}^{2g}$.
2. On the other hand, let's upgrade Riemann's theorem to the Riemann--Roch theorem, which says that if $K$ is the canonical bundle (i.e. the bundle of holomorphic 1-forms) on $X$, then
   $$l(D)-l(K-D) = \mathrm{ deg}\, D + 1 -\gamma.$$
   (I changed $g$ to $\gamma$ because *a priori* this isn't the same as the previous $g$; indeed, that's what we want to prove.) Applying this with $D=0$ we get 
   $$1-l(K) = 1-\gamma$$
   hence $l(K)=\gamma$. Now $l(K)$ by definition means the dimension of the space of global sections of the bundle $K$ of holomorphic 1-forms on $X$. Another notation for the same space is $H^0(X,\Omega^1)$, so we have $\mathrm{dim} \, H^0(X,\Omega^1)=\gamma$.

The statement of Hodge decomposition for curves is the following:

\begin{align} 
H^1(X,\mathbf{C}) = H^0(X,\Omega^1) \oplus H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \end{align}

and moreover the two direct summands on the right-hand side are *conjugate*, hence have the same dimension $\gamma$. (Don't worry about what $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ actually is if you don't know the definition of sheaf cohomology; all that matters is that it has dimension $\gamma$.)

Now we know the dimensions of both sides of the displayed formula from 1. and 2. above, and plugging them in we get 
$$2g=\gamma+\gamma;$$ 
that is, $g=\gamma$!

**Edit:** Maybe it's worthwhile mentioning a simpler proof for *plane* curves of the equality of these two numbers.

First of all, it's easy to deduce from the Riemann–Roch theorem that the degree of the canonical line bundle $K$ is

$$\text{deg} \, K = 2\gamma - 2.$$

On the other hand, if $X$ is a smooth curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbf{P}^2$, one can write down an explicit nonzero regular differential $\omega$ on $X$, and observe that it has $d(d-3)$ zeroes. Since $\omega$ is a section of $K$, this shows that

$$\text{deg} \, K = d(d-3).$$
Comparing these two expressions for the degree, we find that $\gamma=\frac12 (d-1)(d-2)$.

So our goal is now to show that the topological genus $g(X)$ is also equal to $\frac12 (d-1)(d-2)$. To do this, we use the fact that $X$ is a degree-$d$ branched cover of $\mathbf P^1$ with $d(d-1)$ ramification points (to see this, project from a general point in $\mathbf P^2$). This gives the formula
$$\chi(X) = 2d -d(d-1);$$
since $\chi(X)=2-2g$, this simplifies to give $g=\frac12 (d-1)(d-2)$, as required.

Comment: I should emphasise that this is _not_ how Riemann and friends knew that $g=\gamma$. Instead, they would have thought in terms of integrating 1-forms (i.e. sections of $\Omega^1$) around loops in $X$ (i.e. elements of $H_1$). But I'll leave it to someone else to explain that story...

Comment: For details on the edit (in particular, how to construct $\omega$), see Chapter 6 of Kirwan, _Complex Algebraic Curves_.

Comment: Something to be noted. First, every compact Riemann surface (i.e. every compact complex manifold is a projective variety. Reference Hartshorn appendix). Therefore given a compact Riemann surface $C$ it make sense to talk about the its algebraic cohomology. Next, every complex 1-d manifold is an orientable 2-d closed real manifold. By classification theorem, this reduce the topology of $C$ to be torus of genus $g$. The rest is Kahler manifold, Hodge decomposition, de Rham cohomology $\cong$ singular cohomology, Kahler differential sheaf on $C$ pullback to holomorphic $1$-form sheaf on $C$.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, you need the curve $X$ to be non-singular if you want the complex and algebraic genus to agree. Moreover, the definitions are unified by taking $X$ over the base field $\mathbb{C}$ and taking the topological genus of the resulting complex curve, i.e. surface of real dimension two.

I would suggest you look at the [Riemann-Roch Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem) which gives a statement similar to the theorem you gave, but in terms of an equality. The [proof of which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem#Proof) involves some very hard maths.

Comment: In the proof of the Riemann Roch theorem, the genus $g$ is that defined by Fulton. There is no mention to its topological meaning.

Comment: @Galoisfan Where does it say that? The proof is in terms of homology and cohomology which is intrinsically topological. The proof starts with the left hand side in terms of divisors etc, applies cohomology theory, finds an isomorphic dual and then notes that that is the Euler characteristic. The other answer to this question also uses the Riemann-Roch theorem.

Comment: FlybyNight: I agree with @Galoisfan here. The (sketch) proof at that Wikipedia page says "we find the Euler characteristic of the structure sheaf i.e. $1-g$ by definition". If you define $g$ that way, you must do some work to show it has _anything_ to do with the topological genus. Moreover, you say "the proof is in terms of homology and cohomology which is intrinsically topological." That's not true; the proof only use the notion of cohomology of coherent sheaves, which makes perfect sense for varieties over any field.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Very interesting. But can't the dual of a cohomology group be interpreted as a homology group? The sketch finds a dual, which I was interpreting as a homological.

Comment: @FlybyNight: the point is that there are two entirely different kinds of cohomology groups floating around in this discussion: _singular cohomology_, which is the topological object, and which satisfies the duality statement you mention; and _cohomology of coherent sheaves_, which makes sense for algebraic varieties which are not necessarily complex manifolds. Riemann--Roch as discussed on Wikipedia only talks about the latter; to make the connection between the two, you need some extra ingredient, for instance the Hodge decomposition I mentioned.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Brilliant. Thanks for that. I think I learned something. I'll delete my post in a few minutes. You obviously know a lot about co/homology and your presence on this site is a great asset.

Comment: @FlybyNight: ok, glad I could help!

Comment: @FlybyNight Reminder of the above exchange (in case you forgot).