# Riemann's genus???

Tags: math-history

Could anyone provide me with Riemann's original definition of genus? It would be great if, apart from the definiton in English and some example he may have illustrated the notion with, you could also give me the original German definition (even as copy of the manuscript).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riemann's result (and definition) of the genus of an abstract curve, i.e. a function field is as follows:

> Für einen Funktionenkörper $K$ gibt es nur von $K$ abhängige natürliche Zahlen $g$ und $N$, so dass für beliebige Divisoren $D$ auf $K$ die Ungleichung
>   $$
> g ≥ \deg D + 1 − \dim  L(D)
> $$
>   erfüllt ist und für alle Divisoren vom Grad mindestens $N$ Gleichheit gilt.
>   Die natürliche Zahl $g$ wird als das Geschlecht des Funktionenkörpers $K$ bezeichnet.

For more information see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544342/genus-of-a-curve-topology-vs-algebraic-geometry).

Comment: Just for kicks, ran this through Google translate: For a functional body K is only available from K-dependent natural numbers g and N, so that for arbitrary divisors D on K the inequality
$$g≥degD+1−dimL(D)$$
is fulfilled and is valid for all divisors of degree at least N equality. The natural number g is called the sex of the function field K. LOL

Comment: Don't useGoogle translate for math texts with ambiguous vocabulary. "For a function field $K$ there are natural numbers $g$ nd $N$ that depend only on $K$ such that for arbitrary divisors $D$ on $K$ the inequality $$ g\ge\deg D+1-\dim L(D)$$ holds, with equality for all divisors of degree at least $N$. The natural number $g$ is called the *genus* of the function field $K$."

Comment: Thanks. Geschlecht in German can be translated both as sex and as gender, depending of the context. So the literate use of Latin genus is very adequate.

Comment: By the way, I assumed this would be found in [Theorie der Abel'schen Functionen](http://www.emis.de/classics/Riemann/AbelFn.pdf), but I don't find any of the words "Geschlecht", "Genus", "Divisor", "Funktionenkörper", "Functionenkörper" in the linked pdf.

Comment: AS far as I know, Riemann defined the temr in a text from 1857. I am not sure which text it was, though.