# What was Riemann's proof that geometric genus equals arithmetic genus for a smooth curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

There is a [fantastic answer here explaining the connection between geometric and arithmetic genus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/544371/18240). In a comment to the answer, the author writes:

> I should emphasize that this is not how Riemann and friends knew that
>   $g=\gamma$. Instead, they would have thought in terms of integrating
>   1-forms (i.e. sections of $\Omega^1$) around loops in X (i.e. elements
>   of $H_1$). But I'll leave it to someone else to explain that story...

How does this story go?

Edit: @Chappers suggests the answer may be in a paper of Riemann's on Abelian functions. Here is an English translation in two parts: [Part I](http://archive.larouchepac.com/files/Riemann_AbelianFunctions1_0.pdf), [Part II](http://archive.larouchepac.com/files/Riemann_AbelianFunctions2_0.pdf).

Comment: Once upon a time there was a poor, shy, sickly PhD student called Bernhard Riemann. He worked at an isolated backwater university called Göttingen, and had a wicked supervisor called Gauss...

Comment: But anyway, if I remember correctly, this is in Riemann's large paper on Abelian functions, 

*Theorie der Abel'schen Functionen*
(Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, 54 (1857))

There's a copy in German [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Papers.html), or I can dig out my English edition later.

Comment: @Chappers Thanks for the reference. I found an English translation, which I  linked to in the question. I'll try to search through it for the answer soon.

Comment: Some useful comments of roy smith on this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211544/euler-characteristic-of-a-curve